# perform sql query and display results in modal after table row press

Tags: javascript, html, sql, asp.net

I have a dynamically filled `table` from a SQL database. Each row is clickable via some java script on the page.

What i need is to perform a SQL query to find a row that matched the id of the row that was clicked and then display those results in the bootstrap `modal`. (`textfields` such as first name, last name ect).

I'm struggling to understand how to do this as i am pressing a table row that is not posting back to the server so I don't understand how to perform the query.

script to display the `modal`:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".table_row_click").click(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', "#myModal");
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });
});
```

`model`:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'
  aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable' role='document'>
     <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
           <h3 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>Supplier information</h3>
           <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
           <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='ids'>ID:</label><input class="form-control" required='required'  type="text" placeholder="" readonly></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='name'>Name:<span style="color:red">*</span></label><input class='form-control firstname' required='required' type='text' name='name'
              placeholder='Enter first name' /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='country'>Country:</label><input class='form-control lastname'  type='text' name='country' placeholder='Enter Country' 
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='state'>State:</label><input class='form-control phone'  type='text' name='state' placeholder='Enter State'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_name'>Street Name:</label><input class='form-control email'  type='text' name='street_name' placeholder='Enter Street Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='street_number'>Street #:</label><input class='form-control address' type='text' name='street_number' placeholder='Enter Street #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone1'>Phone # 1:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone1'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='phone2'>Phone # 2:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='phone2'  placeholder='Enter Phone # 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email1'>Email 1:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email1'  placeholder='Enter Email 1'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='email2'>Email 2:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='email2'  placeholder='Enter Email 2'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_first_name'>Rep First Name:</label><input class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_first_name'   placeholder='Enter Rep First Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_last_name'>Rep Last Name:</label><input class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='rep_last_name'  placeholder='Enter Rep Last Name'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_phone'>Rep Phone #:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_phone'  placeholder='Enter Rep Phone #'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='rep_email'>Rep Email:</label><input class='form-control birthday'  type='text' name='rep_email'  placeholder='Enter Rep Email'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='website'>Website:</label><input class='form-control birthday' type='text' name='website'  placeholder='Enter Website'
              /></div>
           <div class='form-group'><label for='gender' >Active:<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
              <span  style="color:green"><input  required='required'  type='radio' name='Active' value='True' />True</span>
              <span  style="color:red"><input  required='required' type='radio' name='Active' value='False' />False</span>
           </div>
           <button class='btn btn-primary btn-save-change'
              type='submit'>Save changes</button>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
```

Dynamically created `table` via SQL query:

```
    <div id="MainContent_myDiv">
    <div class='container test'>
        <div class='panel panel-primary filterable test'>
            <div class='panel-heading panel-heading-custom test'>
                <p style='text - align:left; font-size:24px'>Suppliers <span style='float:right;'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-="" data-target='#myModal' style='font-size:15px' type='button'><span style='float:right;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' style='color: rgb(59, 237, 45)'></span> New</span> <button class='btn btn-default btn-sm btn-filter' style='font-size:15px' type='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-filter'></span> Filter</button></button></span></p>
            </div>
            <table class='table table-hover test' id='myTable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr class='filters shadow'>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(0)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='#' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(1)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Name' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='number' onclick='sortTable(2)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Phone # 1' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='number' onclick='sortTable(3)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Phone # 2' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(4)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Email 1' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(5)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Email 2' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(6)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Website' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                        <th data-type='string' onclick='sortTable(7)'><input class='form-control' disabled placeholder='Active' style='cursor: pointer' type='text'></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class='shadow'>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>45</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>suppliername1</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>45</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>0450591234</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>aaron@outlook.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>aaront@outlook.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>www.website.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>False</td>
                        <td><button class='btn btn-outline-danger button_border' data-target='#exampleModalCenter' data-toggle='modal' id='45' onclick='change(this.id)' style='font - size:20px' type='button'><i class='material-icons'>Del</i></button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='shadow'>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>46</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>suppliername2</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>0450591234</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>0450591234</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>aaront@outlook.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>aarontexample@outlook.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>www.website.com</td>
                        <td class=' table_row_click'>False</td>
                        <td><button class='btn btn-outline-danger button_border' data-target='#exampleModalCenter' data-toggle='modal' id='46' onclick='change(this.id)' style='font - size:20px' type='button'><i class='material-icons'>Del</i></button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking that maybe i could call a c# function on a post-back on the row click that does the query and then reloaded the page with the data and displays the modal. (opposed to the JavaScript displaying the modal)

Comment: There's many ways you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways you can do this, eg full on asp.net controls or an ajax call to an endpoint to load in your data.

If you're comfortable with postbacks and .net but want the modal to appear quickly you could:

- On click on the row, grab the id and put it into a value of a hidden field
- Wrap your modal body in an updatePanel
- Make all your textboxes runat server
- Put an asp:button inside that panel and click it with a jquery click()
- Now handle the onclick event in your c# code behind to hit up your database and set the values of your fields

Have fun!

Comment: How can i do all of that from just clicking the row though? i.e without having to click a button.

Comment: i am kinda new to asp.net and don't quite understand